# Positive definiteness of a Matrix

Tags: schur-complement, linear-matrix-inequalities

$K>0\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $P>0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are diagonal positive definite matrices. And $R\geq 0\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is positive semi-definite matrix. Let $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $n>m$ . Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a rank-deficient matrix.

I am trying to find the conditions on $K$ (existance) such that, the matrix
\begin{eqnarray}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
K-P+B R B^\top & KA\\
A^\top K &A^\top K A
\end{bmatrix}}_{M}\geq 0
\end{eqnarray}.

PS: 
I have tried Schur's compliment analysis on $M$, It didn't give me any useful result. So , I have tried the following
\begin{eqnarray}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
K-P+B R B^\top & KA\\
A^\top K &A^\top K A
\end{bmatrix}}_{M}=
\begin{bmatrix}
I&O\\O&A^\top
\end{bmatrix}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
K-P+B R B^\top & K\\
 K & K 
\end{bmatrix}}_{N}
\begin{bmatrix}
I&O\\O&A
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

This implies $M\geq 0$ if $N>0$. Note that this only sufficient but not necessary. Using Schur's compliment analysis on $N$ we get
\begin{eqnarray}
K&>&0\\
K-P+B R B^\top-K(K)^{-1}K&>&0
\end{eqnarray}
The above second equation implies $BRB^\top-P>0$, which is a contradiction as $P>0$ and $BRB^\top\geq 0$. This does not imply that $M\geq 0$ as the contradiction, that is derived from $N$ is only sufficient but not Necessary.